# How to run a code written in vs through command prompt

Tags: visual-studio-2012, command-line, console-application

I have always developed in Linux using gcc for my C programs. Now I am forced to use Windows. I have completed a quick program in Visual Studio express 2012. It is a console application with input arguments.

With Linux I can just use `./programname input1 input2`.

How do I do that in the Windows command prompt? If not, does anyone know a good tutorial on deploying my console application from Visual Studio? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically do it the same way as you would have done it on Linux.

If you have built your program you just need to navigate to the directory where the .exe file resides (using `cd`) as you would on Linux.

And then just run `programname input1 input2`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a "programname.exe" in the current directory, you can simply type:

```
programname input1 input2
```